# Get Thumbnails from any file even ones that are not in the thumbs.db

Tags: delphi, api, thumbnails

I need to extract Thumbnails from files in a Folder.
I tried with [this example](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3806.asp?SK=) but it doesn´t always work.
It gives me thumbnails of images and PDF files, but not of Word, Excel, Text, OpenOffice, etc. files.

*Edit: What I mean with "It doesn't work" is "It doesn't return the image I expect. It returns the icon of the application used to open the file.*

*Edit 2: Windows Explorer **does show me** thumbnails of the files I mention "not working" (.xls, .doc, , .ppt, .odt, .ods)*

Comment: when you open up windows explorer can u see thumbails of word excel etc ?

Comment: -1 "It doesn't work" is never a valid description of a problem. In what way does it not work? What and where are there errors?

Comment: Sorry @David Heffernan "It doesn't work" means it doesn't return the image I expect (Thumbnail of the document). In the example, if it fails to return the thumbnail it returns the icon of the application used to open that kind of file.

Comment: @opc0de Yes, Windows Explorer **does show me** thumbnails of the files I mention "not working" (.xls, .doc, , .ppt, .odt, .ods)

Comment: Downvote removed, question is now improved.

Comment: EDIT: Changed title. I think it's now reflecting the actual question more accurately. Do you agree David?

Comment: @Warren Hmm, it's a bit provocative towards opc0de's answer though

Comment: It seems the OP really wants some API that goes beyond the XP era IExtractImage capabilities, and that opc0de knows the OP wants that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mistaken. Not all .doc and .xls files are saved with thumbnails. Certainly .txt files are not saved with thumbnails.

I downloaded the demo code and tried it out. It successfully shows thumbnails for .doc and .xls that showed thumbnails in Explorer. It shows standard icons for those files that do not have thumbnails when viewed in Explorer.

Comment: Which version of Windows / MS Office / OpenOffice did you tryed on? I'm on a Windows XP + OpenOffice

Comment: Win7/Office2010. But that doesn't matter in my view. You were talking about thumbnails for text files. That sounds like you have some weird extension in Explorer that shows you that but doesn't do it via `IExtractImage`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tool witch reads Thumbs.db file extracting images from it i hope it helps (source provided )

https://sites.google.com/site/delphibasics/home/delphibasicsprojectreleases/thumbsdbviewer

I don't know why the code you posted doesn't work properly it should...

Comment: why is that...if he said explorer shows the thumbs then that will work

Comment: Thumbs in Thumbs.db may not be the right size, and may also not contain anything for a file. They are created on demand by explorer.

Comment: True!...but until someone pops with a better idea i will keep this answer

Comment: The OP is asking it seems for a way to use Explorer's own functionality in a way for which no public documentation exists. Nobody should downvote opc0de because he answered this question with the title as originally written by the OP. I changed the title because the OP was particularly nonplussed by the answer to his question, and I felt the situation was unfair to the answerers.

Comment: @Warren It is my contention that Explorer doesn't do anything more than `IExtractThumbnail`.

Comment: Explorer might not have anything else built-in, but explorer extensions in Windows might be on this guys computer and he might be looking for a way to harness the capabilities of those shell extensions.